# Shorthand of Deedle create new series of fixed length

Tags: c#, deedle

What is the best practice to create an empty Series of fixed length LEN ?

This is what I use now, a bit verbose with Enumerable Range and .Select()

```
Deedle.Series<int, double> newFixedSeries = Enumerable.Range(0, LEN).Select(idx => 0d).ToOrdinalSeries();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using looks completely reasonable to me. If you want to make it nicer, you can always define your own helper method and then use that. Another alternative I can think of is to use the `Series` constructor, which is a little bit shorter, but not hugely:

```
// Your original approach
var s = Enumerable.Range(0, LEN).Select(idx => 0d).ToOrdinalSeries();

// Using the Series constructor
var s = new Series<int, float>(new int[10], new float[10]);
```

That said, the Deedle series is an immutable data type, so I cannot think of many cases where you would actually need to create a series filled with zeros - there is not much you can do with such a series. I expect that the thing you are trying to do with the zero-filled series might be better done in some other way.

Comment: thanks for reminding that Deedle series is immutable data type!